# HTML Button that saves and move to the next page

Tags: php, html, button

I have a small problem. I want to have a button in my html page that saves every data that is added in the textfields and also when I click it to move to the next page.

My code is the follow...

```
<input type=button onClick="location.href='education.php'" value='Next'>
```

but it only moves to next page it does not save the data in the database ...

Can you help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: a possible approach could be to send the form fields to the server which then saves those fields into the database

Comment: @S.Pols — GET would not be appropriate for a form that causes data to be inserted into a database.

Comment: @NickBourlai — You have three answers so far and the *all* tell you what type of button you need for that.

Comment: @Quentin some like that ...
<input type=button onClick="location.href='text.php'" value='Next'>

But it does not save it

Comment: @NickBourlai — You need to look at the *answers* not at the wrong code you wrote in your original question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Insert Query Put here

header('Location: education.php');
}

?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**education.php** :

```
   <?php
   echo "Successfully Updated.";
?>
```

Comment: I dont want to just save, I can do that , I want to save it AND move to the next page ... For example I want to go to skills.php

Comment: @NickBourlai, Same is done here. what actually you want ?..in this answer on click the submit.it first save the data in database and then redirect to the education.php

Comment: add ';' after header('Location: education.php');  otherwise it gives you an error.

Comment: @NickBourlai, PHP statements end with a semicolon (;). thats why we have to use ';' at the end of every statement, otherwise it gives you an error.

Comment: yes I know my friend but you forgot it to write it after the header('Location: education.php')

PS: THANKS FOR THE SOLUTION

Comment: @NickBourlai, ooh..i forgot to write..now i updated my answer please check..thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the JavaScript
2. Change the `type` to `submit`
3. Wrap it in a `<form>`
4. Set the `action` of the form to `education.php`
5. Set the `method` of the form to `post`

Then, in `education.php`, read the data from `$_POST` and use [PDO (with bound variables)](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) to insert it into the database.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to set an action to your form like below because you are not submitting the form, but just redirection to another page without taking the form data.

```
<form action="education.php" method="post">
   <!-- All your input fields here -->
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

and your education.php should be look like this:

```
<?php
//Get all parameters using $_POST
//Make A connection to database
//Choose a database in which you have to save the data
//Create a SQL query
// run query using mysql_query($query);
//Redirect to anywhere with header("Location:page.php");

?>
```

Comment: That's not the question. He wants to save the textfields and redirect to `education.php`. Who says `education.php` will handle the post?

Comment: This will save it , it will not move me to the next page for example skills.php

Comment: header("Location:skills.php"); after saving to database.